# Обновление фигуры в OpenGL в Android при выводе через SurfaceView

Tags: android, opengl

Добрый день. Строю фигуру в OpenGL по координатам и вывожу через SurfaceView на экран. Изначально координаты фигуры ( X и Y) задаются кодом, но хочу сделать, чтобы они вводились с экрана. Для этого сделал ввод через EditTExt, координаты получаю и передаю в OpenGl, но получается, что нужно как-то перестроить фигуру с новыми координатами, а как это сделать?

Comment: передать новые координаты в OpenGL перерисовать и вывести через SurfaceView на экран.

Comment: Новые коррдинаты передаю в матрицу вместо первоначальных, вопрос как перерисовать фигуру?

Comment: в onDrawFrame передать нужные данные

Comment: А какие данные в onDrawFrame передавать? Я делаю по этому примеру http://esate.ru/blogs/freaky-brainstorm/4237/?sphrase_id=8227
Координаты в отдельном классе(Object3D), я в него их и передаю. Координаты заменяются, но картинка не перерисовывается